# Rails caches_page :index in Wrong Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I have a controller *Projects* in my Rails app with:

```
caches_page :index
```

However, instead of the cached file being generated at `/public/projects/index.html` it is located at `/public/projects.html`.

The web server (currently Mongrel) looks for `*/` directories before `*.html` files. So the `http://…/projects` request is routed through Rails and my index cache file is never served.

How can I tell `caches_page :index` to generate the file at `/public/projects/index.html` instead?

Comment: what is your root route in the routes.rb file?  There is something else going on if it's not naming the cache file index.html

Comment: My root route is:

`map.root :controller => 'static', :action => ‘home’`

My Project route is:

`map.resources :projects`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the directory by adding the following to your environment.rb config block

```
config.cache_store = :file_store, "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/projects"
```

A couple other things:

1. The cache settings have changed some
   with the different version of Rails,
   it would be helpful to know what
   version you are running
2. In general you're probably better off using the cache memory store instead of file store (if you have sufficient RAM in your box).

Comment: I’m using Rails 2.3.5. I might give memcaching a go, but RAM is likely to be tight, and I trust Apache to serve my small, low-traffic site efficiently. However, I’m not trying to change the cache root, just the caching behaviour of the index action.